# How to do I batch change icons of folders in Windows 10?

Tags: batch, icons

I have a folder of 10 folders and I would like to change each folder to a different icon. Each of those icons is already made in another folder. (each folder will have a different icon)

How would I automate or batch this task to save me having to do it indivually. As I will have more sets of icons to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is 3 years late but here we go

you can manually bulk change folders' icons by

- applying read-only attribute to the folders.
- applying read-only attribute to desktop.ini files inside the folders.
- the desktop.ini should correctly refer to the icon we want.

> STEP 1: ACTIVATE POWERSHELL & CREATE POWERSHELL SCRIPT

Start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as Administrator" option. Only members of the Administrators group on the computer can change the execution policy.

Enable running unsigned scripts by entering:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

in notepad copy this code and save the file as script.ps1 in the directory D:\icons\

```
<# copy desktop.ini recursively #>
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory|
    foreach { copy "D:\Icons\desktop.ini" $_.FullName}

<# set folder attribute readonly recursively #>
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory|
    foreach {$_.Attributes = 'readonly'}

<# set attribute readonly for desktop.ini recursively #>
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include *.ini|
    foreach {$_.Attributes = 'readonly,hidden'}

<# set attribute hidden for folder.ico recursively #>
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include *.ico|
    foreach {$_.Attributes = 'hidden'}
```

in notepad copy this code and save the file as enable_icons.bat in the directory D:\icons\

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -Command "D:\icons\script.ps1"
PAUSE
```

> STEP 2: CREATE DESKTOP.INI FILE

in notepad copy this code and save the file as DESKTOP.INI in the directory D:\icons\

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=folder.ico,0
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic
```

now inside the directory D:\icons\ we should have 3 files

- desktop.ini
- enable_icons.bat
- script.ps1

> STEP 3: SENDTO FOLDER

copy enable_icons.bat to sendto folder

use either of these to access it

```
c:\users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

or

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

> FINAL STEP : HOW TO APPLY

1. Inside each folder, place your icon and rename it to `folder.ico`
2. Select [**parent folder**] of [folders you want to change their icons] >
   right click > send to > enable-icons

if you already have **only** **ONE** icon file inside each folder use this batch script to rename them all.

in notepad copy this code and save the file as rename_icons.bat in the same directory as
[**parent folder**]

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /r %%A IN (*.ico) DO (
echo.
echo "%%A"
REN "%%~fA" "folder.ico")

pause
```

now drag the  [parent folder] to rename_icons.bat

.
.
.
.
**A VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:**

**This is very powerful that it may affect neighboring folders**

**(in other words it works but too well and someone smarter can fix it)**

**for the time being, MAKE SURE THAT  [parent folder] is the only folder in the directory**

Comment: You are right; it does work too well, even though I have done exactly as you described, all the folders on my harddrive, parents, children, doesn't matter, got a 'desktop.ini' now. Time to clean up I guess ^^ (I got what I asked for haha)

Answer (score 0):

Where are the actual icons you are going to apply to the folders?

If they are not within a `.dll` file, you could make one using the free 30-day trial of [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/index.html) or some similar software.

Within each folder there is a hidden file called `desktop.ini`.  They have the file system attributes of S (System), A (Files ready for archiving) as well as H (Hidden).  You can see these by adding the Attributes column in an Explorer window.

The `desktop.ini` files look like this for a standard yellow folder:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

In a `desktop.ini` file in one your [already] customised folder, the important lines are `IconFile`, which points to the location of your `icon.dll` file that you made, and the `IconIndex` line, which points to the particular coloured icon within the file.

You copy the same file to each of the folders you want to customise, but the `IconIndex` value will be different, depending on the colour.  Make sure that they have the HSA attributes.

Comment: I've done as you have said just changing the iconindex as well as the iconfile, but its not working. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @AasimAzam Try removing the other two lines. Are you sure you got the `IconIndex` number right, with the `-` beforehand?  More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I did one folder manually by right clicking and changing folder icon and then copying the resulting desktop.ini file with the appropriate changes in another folder. 

Does the icon dll need to be in the c drive or can it be in d drive?

Comment: @AasimAzam It can be anywhere, but it is better to keep it on C: and use `%SystemRoot%` instead of `C:` in the path (in case the system drive is not C:), as then other machines will see the same icon when using network drives (as long as the other machines also have the .dll file in the same location).  You could alternatively put the file on a network drive, but the icon won't show up as fast.