# How to change all folder icons within a folder windows 10

Tags: windows, icons, user-folders

I would like to change all folder icons within a folder in Windows 10.

Do I have to do them all manually? Or is there an option to change all icons within that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program called `Folder Maker` which allows you to, through a user interface program, select the folders that you want and change the icon.

You can select multiple folders and customize them:
[image: initial program image]

[image: select multiple folders]

Above I have some folders in the "User Icons" tab that I like to use.

Then you can change them with "Apply":
[image: Apply changes]

And the it's done:

[image: my folders example]

You can download program at:
https://foldermarker.com/en/

They have a Free version (which is this one in my example) and a payed one that has more features such as change ALL THE SUBFOLDERS INSIDE (which I think it's great). You can test this version also for 30 days free of charge.

Download links:
https://foldermarker.com/en/buynow/

Answer (score 1):

I think the script solutions Mikey linked to can be improved upon. If you first customize the icon of the parent folder, that can then easily be copied to all subfolders. You can change or delete the parent customizatioin after copying if it needs to be different. Just copy & paste the following code into a **PowerShell** window & press  to execute.

```
$Prompt = 'Select Parent Folder'
$Source = ((New-Object -Com shell.application).BrowseForFolder(0,$Prompt,0)).Self.Path
If ( Test-Path $Source ) {
    Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory -Recurse | ForEach {
        Copy-Item "$Source\Desktop.ini" $_.FullName -Force
        $_.Attributes += 'ReadOnly'
    }
    Echo "`n`t`tSuccess!!!`n"
}
```

Comment: I don't see any comments by anyone named Mikey - can you elaborate? What does the complex $Source variable do exactly? Thanks

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010: Neither do I, at this point, but I'd like to *think* they existed when I posted my answer :-s  The statement `((New-Object -Com shell.application).BrowseForFolder(0,$Prompt,0)).Self.Path` displays the ***Browse for Folder*** dialog and returens the path to the folder selected in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in the GUI. Attempting to select multiple folders and going through the properties menu results in only one being changed.

There is a script provided over [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1142609/how-to-do-i-batch-change-icons-of-folders-in-windows-10) that can make the change for you with a specific `.ico` file.